# Drupal equivalent of Starkers

Tags: 7, theming

As most of you probably know when themeing in Wordpress you can use Starkers as your base theme. This clears up the view to show pure semantics so you can style and theme cleanly.

Is there an equivalent for Drupal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're looking for clean and easy base themes, there's [Stark](http://drupal.org/project/stark) (which has a contrib version, as well as the version in Drupal core)

> This contrib version of Stark is an exact copy of the one in Drupal 7
>   core with one exception. This version now uses a responsive design that matches a Drupal 8 proposal to make Stark use a responsive layout.

There's also [Mothership](http://drupal.org/project/mothership), which I've never used - but it looks pretty awesome!

> The Mothership is a HTML5 base theme that offers a workaround to
>   Drupal’s obscure love for wrapping everything in 2 divs and slapping
>   on 3 CSS classes wherever possible.

Comment: Thanks for the rapid response. Would love to use Twitter Bootstrap straight out but seems like Mothership might be offering a simple thing.

Comment: for bootstrap you can use the bootstrap theme.

Comment: Even though Stark and Mothership can be used as minimalist base themes, there is a huge difference between them. Stark does as little as possible and is meant to expose the default markup as generated by modules. Mothership relentlessly overrides all default markup in an attempt to generate the leanest and cleanest markup possible. It's just a matter of taste I guess (just like my personal preference for [Aurora](http://drupal.org/project/aurora) and [Zen](http://drupal.org/project/zen)).

Comment: Bootstrap for Drupal has a _lot_ of bugs, I'd give that one a miss for now

Comment: Thanks for that heads up Clive. I'm going to install Mothership have a look at the output....and probably override its CSS framework and replace with Twitter Bootstrap CSS.

Comment: If I was going to use Bootstrap, I'd *probably* just go all out and make my theme from scratch.  I'm a big fan of Zen (I can *never* decide between Zen/Omega) - but as a direct comparison, Stark is probably closest to Starkers...

Comment: ....oh how I now wish I'd used Mothership on the first Drupal site I developed